# I accidentally obfuscated all my files when using oracle sql developer. Now I can't login into my system [ubuntu]

Tags: ubuntu

I clicked on the obfuscate button in my root directoty in oracle sql without knowing what it does. Then my system crashed and now no matter how many times I restart, i'm stuck at a login page. It accepts my passsword and then immediately takes me back to the login page.

I use Ubuntu 21.04.

Is there any way to recover from this?

Comment: You can't log in to your Ubuntu desktop? What does it have to do with database administration?

Comment: Did you do this in SQL Developer?

Answer (score 0):

For completion sake, I accidentally obfuscated my root folder from SQL Developer. I was able to fix it by deleting all my old config files.